# Are questions about EFI boot menu configuration on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

**TL;DR – skip to the emphasised parts.**

I came across [this question](//askubuntu.com/questions/833581/choose-os-from-bios-menu-not-grub-2-efis-3-disks) asking for instruction and explanation on

1. **how to configure the EFI BIOS boot menu to contain an entry for each operating system on a multi-boot setup** and
2. how to configure Grub so that it skips to Ubuntu right away (because we already made our choice at an earlier stage).

**I'm sure the 2nd is on topic but what about the 1st?** Afaik EFI BIOS configuration isn't something that's part of Ubuntu or can be controlled with Ubuntu. On top of that, there are heaps of wildly different EFI implementations out there depending on the mainboard. The question doesn't even mention which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's both OT and too broad. You aren't supposed to ask multiple questions in one post in the first place, and EFI has nothing to do with Ubuntu besides being able to boot it. GRUB is even only on topic if it specifically relates to the functionality of Ubuntu.

I believe the question should be closed. EFI isn't Ubuntu, so we can't support that, and it's a double question, which we don't support either.

Answer (score 6):

I do not think it is OT; too broad, ok, if it includes specifics for another OS.

I would rephrase it to "How do I edit the EFI menu". Ubuntu does provide the tools for that (efibootmgr).

We are here to help people, not follow rigid guidelines.

Comment: The question itself is a helpful question that has been used as a link to help users who have similar questions. If it keeps on being linked to that way, the question will gain a large number of views, which is another indication that it is a useful question.

Comment: @karel: I don't see many views on that question – specially if you subtract the views of this meta-question. No inbound links either.

Comment: I linked to that question. In fact I also asked a [question about EFI on Ask Ubuntu Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14406/should-efi-be-a-synonym-of-uefi) which wasn't answered and got not many views. I don't think there is much general interest in EFI, so I don't much care if a question about EFI is too broad, otherwise how would the information that I want to know get out there.